# Can every "noodly" space be decomposed into one or more manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory, connectedness, quotient-spaces

**The Premise:**

Let $X$ be a topological space. For any pair of points $x_0,x_1\in X$, let $\mathrm N_X(x_0,x_1)$ be the set of all subspaces $S$ of $X$ such that $x_0,x_1\in S$ and $S\cong I$ for some interval $I\subseteq\Bbb R$.

We say that $X$ is "noodly" if and only if

1. $X$ is second countable
2. $X$ is Hausdorff
3. $X$ is locally metrizable
4. $X$ is path connected and contains at least two distinct points (equivalent: $X$ is arc-connected, $\mathrm N_X(x_0,x_1)\ne\emptyset$ for all $x_0,x_1\in X$)
5. $\bigcup_{x\in X}\bigcup\mathrm N_X(x_0,x)=X$ for all $x_0\in X$

Every connected topological manifold is trivially noodly, and gluing along noodly subspaces preserves noodliness. The gluing of disjoint (though not necessarily distinct) manifolds provides the motivating example for noodly spaces (also homotopy stuff, because homotopy is only intuitive for noodly spaces anyway.)

For a noodly space $X$, a "decomposition" of $X$ is a [countable?] set $\mathcal A$ of pairwise disjoint noodly spaces and an equivalence relation $E$ on $\bigcup\mathcal A$ such that $\bigcup \mathcal A/E\cong X$.

**The Question:**

Are there any noodly spaces which *cannot* be decomposed into a set of pairwise disjoint manifolds?

That is, are there any noodly spaces $X$ for which there does *not* exist a set $\mathcal M$ of pairwise disjoint manifolds such that $X\cong\bigcup\mathcal M/E$ for some equivalence relation $E$?

Comment: The condition "$N(x_0,x_1)\neq\emptyset$ for all $x_0,x_1\in X$" is simply the same as "being path connected". In which case condition 5 is implied by it, and so it is not needed at all. So your space is Hausdorff, second countable, locally metrizable and path connected. And therefore a counterexample to your question will be any metric, path connected but not locally path connected space, e.g. the comb space. Am I missing something?

Comment: The discrete space is path connected only if it is a singleton. Indeed, I stand corrected. These two conditions are equivalent if $X$ has at least two points in Hausdorff case anyway. Because in Hausdorff space if you can connect two points by a path, then you can also connected them via path which is a homeomorphism (onto image). That doesn't change much though.

Comment: You may want to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Arc_connectedness The property of being arc connected and path connected are equivalent for Hausdorff.

Comment: @freakish Isn't the comb space $\cong\left([0,1]\cup\coprod_{n\in\Bbb N}[0,1]\right)/E$, where $E(1/n,(n,0))$, $E(0,(0,0))$, and $E(x,x)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: No. Comb space is not locally connected. And a quotient of locally connected space is locally connected. The particular example you talk about fails for the same reason why $\{0,1/2,1/3,1/4,\ldots\}$ is not a quotient of $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition 5 follows from path connectedness, at least under Hausdorff, and thus is redundant.

Therefore spaces that you consider are precisely: second countable, locally metrizable, Hausdorff and path connected. And you ask: is such space a quotient of a (possibly disconnected) manifold? The answer is: not necessarily. Note that manifolds are locally connected, and thus so are their quotients. But there's a simple example of a space that satisfies all those conditions, and additionally is not locally connected: [the comb space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space).